# Hightlight x-axis label in Highcharts

Tags: css, typescript, highcharts, typescript2.0

I have a bar graph in Highcharts and I need to highlight the x-axis label of one of the bar graphs based on an event that is fired. Note that this event is NOT the `click` inside the Highcharts graph but an event that is triggered from the outside.

So far I have managed to get the index of the bar graph that is clicked by doing something like this once the event I am subscribed to is fired

```
 var index = <HighchartsPointObject>this.chart.get('some very unique identifier').category;
```

But I have not yet found a way to actually manually highlight (as in change the CSS color style) of the label at the corresponding index.

Note that I've also tried using the `formatter()` inside the `options` object in a way that is similar to this :

```
formatter(this: { value: string }) {
    var someStaticReference = storedValueFromFiredEvent // get the information I need from that event
        if (someStaticReference.name === this.value) {
            return '<span style="color:#0095d3;">' + this.value + '</span>';
           } else {
               return this.value
           }
}
```

But this does not also do work for me as different bars might have the same names. So I need something based off the index of the bar I need to highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a label object from a tick object. And then modify it with `css()` method.

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function () {
  const tick = chart.get('x-axis-1').ticks[4];
  tick.label.css({
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: 'white'
  });
}
```

The labels by default are text and they do not response for some styles like background-color, so to have ability to change those css, you should se useHTML to true for axis labels.

```
  xAxis: {
    id: 'x-axis-1',
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    labels: {
      useHTML: true
    }
  },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ggouvkv3/